# Apache: Not a GET request error

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm seeing a lot of the following errors in my apache error log coming from a variety of IPs and referrers. Some IPs are my own IP. Most of the URL is referring to one article in my WordPress. Any idea? Thanks.

[warn] [client IP] Not GET request: 2., referer: URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because HTTP is made up of many different types of requests.  One you already know--GET--and others--such as POST--you probably recognize.  A [full list is available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).  Basically, depending on the file being accessed, certain request methods are allowed--in this case, it looks like only GET is expected, and its receiving something else.

This could be due to a variety of issues.  Most likely, a plugin--either for Apache or Wordpress--is getting in the way; try disabling any low-level plugins that deal with caching, compressing, etc., and see if you continue to see those errors.  For example, WP Total Cache (on the WP side), and mod_pagespeed (on the Apache side).

Let me know if you continue to encounter errors.

Andrew

Comment: I think the mod_pagespeed caused the problem. I've upgrade it to the latest version and the problem gone. Thanks.